# Justpy: Add Highcharts Stock Options: "hollowcandlestick" & "Stock Tools"

Tags: charts, highcharts, stock, justpy

- How do I add Highcharts Stock series options to Justpy code?  Specifically, I want to add:

  - hollow candlestick
  - Stock tools
- I am working my way through the Justpy documentation and can't figure out how to change the "series : type" in examples 1 & 2 from "candlestick" to "hollowcandlestick".
- Each of my attempts resulted in a blank webpage. (I also tried "hlc" and got the same result.)
- I also want to add "Stock Tools".  I am guessing the process is about the same as the "hollowcandlestick".  But, I have figured it out yet.
- Note: According to the Highcharts API, Stock tools requires Highcharts version 7.  What version is Justpy using?

Comment: What is your question? The highcharts version used by justpy can be seen in the source code https://github.com/justpy-org/justpy/blob/master/justpy/templates/local/highcharts.js Highstock JS v8.0.4 (2020-03-10)
 (c) 2009-2018 Torstein Honsi

Comment: What do your attempts look like? - please share some code ...

Answer (score 1):

It's important to find out whether [Justpy](https://justpy.io/charts_tutorial/stock_charts/), allow to load addition modules.
While the candlestick series is listed in the documentation, it's [hollowcandlestick](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.hollowcandlestick) modification originally from Highcharts requires an additional module.

It is best to report to Justpy whether they support these series.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

According to the Justpy github readme, they requested such inquires / questions be asked here on stackoverflow tagged with justpy and highcharts.